# Custom template that handles many builds, or one template per build?

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild

I have about 8 builds/definitions that I maintain. I currently have one large custom template that can handle all the builds, however, when I want to add another build it can get a bit dicey rooting around that XAML.  Is it more common to have a smaller template for each build? Would it speed up the time to complete a build?

Comment: What sort of changes are you making to the templates that mean a change to the XAML each time? Also, have you checked out Build vNext it hopefully will make this sort of thing easier in the future.

Comment: The general guideline I give to clients is "Don't modify the build process template unless you have absolutely no other choice." Most custom build actions can be handled via pre/post-build scripts. If you're finding yourself modifying build process templates frequently and you're building .NET applications, chances are you're doing something wrong.

Comment: For a proper answer, you should share some information on what the custom template is doing.

Comment: I just kind of inherited this and thought there must be a better way. Thanks for the guideline @DanielMann

I thought scripts would be fine. Off to get rid of a bloated template!!